# Send/Emit to socket.io without any data?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is it possible to send an event to node js without any data? 
Here's what I am trying to do:

Client:

```
socket.emit('logged out');
```

Server:

```
socket.on('logged out', function() {
    console.log('User is logged out');
    delUser();
    sendUsersOnline();
});
```

The client side is deffinetely being run, but I never get the server side fired. I'm not sure why. It may be because I'm not sending any data?

EDIT:

```
function delUser()
{
    for(i in usersOnline) {
        var user = usersOnline[i];
        if(user.socket_id == socket.id) {
            delete usersOnline[i];
            usersTyping.splice(usersTyping.indexOf(myUser.id), 1);
            console.log('Disconnected: ' + myUser.display_name + '(' + myUser.id + ')');
        }
    }
}

function sendUsersOnline()
{
    io.emit('users online', usersOnline);
}
```

Comment: well what are the functions delUser and sendUsersOnline doing...

Comment: What do you mean by *data*? Parameters? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

According to [Socket.io 2.0.3 docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack) :

> socket.emit(eventName[, ...args][, ack])

```
socket.emit('hello', 'world');
socket.emit('with-binary', 1, '2', { 3:'4', 5: new Buffer(6) });
```

> Emits an event to the socket identified by the string name. Any other
>   parameters can be included. All serializable datastructures are
>   supported, including Buffer.
>
> The ack argument is optional and will be called with the server
>   answer.

It says that any other parameters **can be included but it is not necessary**. So you can definitely send/emit an event without any data from server/client like this

```
socket.emit('logged out');
```

And you can receive any event without data on server/client like this

```
socket.on('logged out', function(){
// Code to execute in response to this event
});
```

I had recently used this type of events to send signals from peer-to-peer **without any data** being sent with it and it works perfectly. Basically one peer(client) send signal to server and than server gets that signal and emits that signal to other peer(client) using broadcast.